# Get category id from post id of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories

I want to get category id from post id of a custom type.
I have the post id, but I can't get it's category id.

I have used so many codes but it doesn't work, may be due to custom post type.

```
$category = get_the_category( $post->ID );
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

`wp_get_post_categories` can only get POST categories not a custom post's categories, try this instead:

```
$category = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-taxonomy-here' );     
foreach ( $category as $cat){
   echo $cat->name;
}
```

Check [this link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_get_post_categories-equivalent-for-custom-taxonomies)

Answer (score 3):

Are your custom post type supporting the standard category taxonomy? If the category used in your custom post type is a custom taxonomy and not the standard category taxonomy you should [`get_the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead of [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category).

```
$categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, "my-custom-taxonomy");
```

Comment: Hi @AmanEsfera!! If your question is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking in the "V" symbol at the left of the answer bellow the vote buttons. This will help other users find the correct answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me:

```
    global $wpdb;

    // get all category id's based on post id
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( " select term_taxonomy_id from " . $wpdb->prefix . "term_relationships where object_id = '" . $post_id . "' " );
    $cats_ids_array = [];
    foreach ( $result as $c ) {
        $cats_ids_array[] = $c->term_taxonomy_id;
    }
```